# I haven't received my verification code from Ubuntu One & tried 3 e-mail addresses!

Tags: ubuntu-one, single-sign-on

The title says it all really!

- I have full connection.
- I have synced 2 AOL accounts and a Zoho account via Evolution Mail.
- I have switched off all filters in all accounts so everything gets filtered through my desktop.
- I have checked the accounts directly to see if anything is amiss.

I'm at a loss! ... help?

Comment: This is about the verification code for Ubuntu Single Sign On, right?

Comment: That's the one.

Comment: Can you check the AOL/Zoho accounts directly rather than sync'ing?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [submitting a support request](https://forms.canonical.com/sso-support/) on the login support form?

They may be able to help you out.

Comment: Just messaged them - I'll keep you posted.
Thank you