# Not receiving Ubuntu One verification code

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one

Its been a three months now that I have signed up for Ubuntu One, but cannot use it because I am not receiving the verification code.

Should I try with another email? I have read the [other posted question about trying with many emails and still failing](https://askubuntu.com/q/20306/196255). What should I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can login to Ubuntu one using a Launchpad account. Create an account on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) and login with that.